# Stable warpfusion error with guided diffusion

Tags: python

I know very little about Python,.

Upon running the stable `warpfusion`, I get error with 'guided_diffusion' module, I already added few new module by using !pip in the code section, but this one is not solved with the same approach.

```
Collecting resize_right   Downloading resize_right-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB) Installing collected packages: resize_right Successfully installed resize_right-0.0.2 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement guided_diffusion (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for guided_diffusion

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-fd10d8c20b27> in <cell line: 32>()
         30 # from CLIP import clip
         31 from resize_right import resize
    ---> 32 from guided_diffusion.script_util import create_model_and_diffusion, model_and_diffusion_defaults
         33 from datetime import datetime
         34 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'guided_diffusion'
```